# Rewrite Rule For Existing File

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have robots.txt and script.php files on my server.
I want to transfer all requests to robots.txt to script.php with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^robots.txt$
RewriteRule .* script.php [F,L]
```

But it doesn't work.
If I delete robots.txt from server - all works great...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `F` forbidden flag I am not sure what is the reason, but there is no requirement for `F` flag try with below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule ^ script.php [L]
```

Comment: Abhisek thank you, but doesn't work still...
If I remove robots.txt from server it works fine, but while robots.txt is present in catalog this doesn't work.

Comment: No, only this one.

Comment: Even when I change the rule for: 
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ script.php 
It's still doesn't work.